# Guard with trailing closure - Swift Syntax

Tags: swift, xcode, closures

Let's say, I have a function which takes a closure as its last parameter, so it can be shortened to something like this:

```
let reminder = reminders.first { (reminder) -> Bool in
    return reminder.mealIdentifier == mealIdentifier
}
```

Awesome! Now let's say I want to put this in a `guard` statement, like this:

```
guard let reminder = reminders.first { (reminder) -> Bool in
    return reminder.mealIdentifier == mealIdentifier
} else {
    continue
}
```

The moment I do this, the compiler starts screaming. The fix is to use no trailing closure short syntax when calling the function, but it's cumbersome as the default auto-completion by Xcode doesn't have an option to NOT do trailing closures short syntaxes when your last parameter is a closure:

```
guard let reminder = reminders.first(where: { (reminder) -> Bool in
   return reminder.mealIdentifier == mealIdentifier
}) else {
    continue
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing here? Or is there a way to somehow have Xcode do autocompletion without the shortened syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is there a way to somehow have Xcode do autocompletion without the shortened syntax?

Xcode is quite smart. It chooses the non-trailing closure version if you do the auto completion in a control flow statement that needs a `{`. For example, if I type:

```
guard let a = reminders.first
```

The auto complete shows:

[image]

If I choose the highlighted option, I get:

```
guard let a = reminders.first(where: <#T##(String) throws -> Bool#>)
```

[image]

If I then press enter, I get:

```
guard let a = reminders.first(where: { (<#String#>) -> Bool in
    <#code#>
})
```

[image]

It doesn't turn it into a trailing closure, as long as you autocomplete within a guard/if statement.